# What is the name of this syntactic construct: "May [Subject] [Verb]"?

Tags: syntax, terminology, spanish

Sentences like "Let such and such be done" or "May this happen". What is the name of this construct?

More examples from Spanish:

- Que ellos entren ahora (Let them in now).
- Que se muerte les satisfagan (May his death satisfy you (pl.))

Answer (score 2):

This is called the [optative mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optative_mood) (though Romance languages like Spanish and French use what is morphologically the [subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#Latin_and_the_Romance_languages) in this role).

Comment: Also the [benedictive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedictive), in Sanskrit. The example given in Wikipedia is _May the Force be with you._

Comment: @jlawler Is the *Let* construction also optative/benefactive, or is it just an imperative?

Comment: @Araucaria That's usually called a jussive or sometimes a hortative.

Comment: You pays your attention and you takes your choice. It depends, really, on the terminology you and your audience are most familiar with, and also on the language families and linguistic theories you want to evoke (if not necessarily use or cite).

Comment: I'd say that "May this happen" is an optative, but "Let such and such be done" looks like an 'open' _let_-imperative -- open in the sense that it is not understood as a directive to the addressee(s) to allow or permit something to happen.

Comment: See these chapters on WALS, btw: https://wals.info/chapter/72 and https://wals.info/chapter/73

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Optative mood is what I was looking for. But subjunctive or not doesn't matter.